# Category controller in prestashop makes an infinite loop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, php-5.6, php-7.1

I move my prestashop site to another server hosting, the same differenet between the old one and this server is PHP version

> NEW server : 7.1 old server : 5.6

In category page I get a infinite loop without any error displayed in page and debug mode is enabled, when I try to see it in my categorycontroller in www/controller/categorycontroller.php

I see that 3 lines make this error I comment them and I don't get the infinite loop, but I don't get the product in this category with message "
There is no product in this category" this error because he don't assing product to category

```
public function initContent()
    {
        //parent::initContent(); (the first line that I commented on)

        $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'category.tpl');

        if ($this->errors) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->customer_access) {
            return;
        }

        if (isset($this->context->cookie->id_compare)) {
            $this->context->smarty->assign('compareProducts', CompareProduct::getCompareProducts((int)$this->context->cookie->id_compare));
        }

        // Product sort must be called before assignProductList()
        $this->productSort();

        $this->assignScenes();

        echo ('<pre>');print_r($this) ;echo ('</pre>');
        //$this->assignSubcategories(); (the second line that I commented on)

        //$this->assignProductList(); (the third line that I commented on)
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'category'             => $this->category,
            'description_short'    => Tools::truncateString($this->category->description, 350),
            'products'             => (isset($this->cat_products) && $this->cat_products) ? $this->cat_products : null,
            'id_category'          => (int)$this->category->id,
            'id_category_parent'   => (int)$this->category->id_parent,
            'return_category_name' => Tools::safeOutput($this->category->name),
            'path'                 => Tools::getPath($this->category->id),
            'add_prod_display'     => Configuration::get('PS_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_DISPLAY'),
            'categorySize'         => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('category')),
            'mediumSize'           => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('medium')),
            'thumbSceneSize'       => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('m_scene')),
            'homeSize'             => Image::getSize(ImageType::getFormatedName('home')),
            'allow_oosp'           => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_OUT_OF_STOCK'),
            'comparator_max_item'  => (int)Configuration::get('PS_COMPARATOR_MAX_ITEM'),
            'suppliers'            => Supplier::getSuppliers(),
            'body_classes'         => array($this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->id, $this->php_self.'-'.$this->category->link_rewrite)
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Have you disabled overrides? Have you disabled non-PrestaShop modules?

Comment: Yes I do this and I don't get any result

Comment: and category controller is don't overrided